# How can I find the PHP STDIN input data type

Tags: php, stdin

I am reading input from STDIN, and I want to find the data type of the given input.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
  $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
  $mystr = fgets($stdin);
  echo gettype(trim($mystr));
  fclose($stdin);
?>
```

and then,

```
Input:  34
Output: string
```

Can anyone please give any idea?

Comment: you tried to remove the `trim`? the return value of `trim` is always a string. the `fgets` returns always a string.

Comment: i was removed trim and checked, but same output..

Comment: without fgets() function, then how will we get the value in stdin?

Comment: yes because `fgets` returns a string too. You can use some `is_*` functions to get the datatype of the input: http://php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php#refsect1-function.gettype-seealso

Comment: no luck, still same output

Comment: I think stdin will always receive "string" you have to check `is_int($mystr)` or other, you can return that type or `(cast)` it to the type you just checked. You could also `(cast)` and check if the contents are equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); // opens a pointer to memory
  $mystr = fgets($stdin); // gets a STRING that you wrote
  echo gettype(trim($mystr)); // returns STRING as is what php gets from you
  fclose($stdin); // closes the pointer
?>
```

If you wanna return the type you will have to manually check this yourself. Like

```
if (is_int($mystr)) {
    return 'int';
}
if (is_bool($mystr) {
    return 'bool';
}
if (is_string($mystr)) {
    return 'string';
}
```

You can also cast your `$mystr` to int like `$mystr = (int) $mystr` and then you can get the type `gettype($mystr)`

If you wanna check if is JSON you can also try and unserialize it and try to find for any issues, if there is , most probably isn't a JSON. return string as a fallback.

You have a bunch of type checks, like:

- is_array
- is_bool
- is_int
- is_string
- is_object
- is_callable

Altho for your scenario from the STDIN you will just need the 3/4 from the list.

Comment: I tried this, but if i use **$mystr = (int) $mystr** and input as 2 means, integer is the output, If i give input as "test" then also gettype returns integer only..:(   @Luis Lopes

Comment: You need to check your input before casting it. Your input will always be a string, and string should be the last thing you would check. I gave you the if scenarios you have to implement. you have to implement all type scenarios you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ctype](http://www.php.net/ctype) library to check the content of your string. In this case you can use `ctype_digit()` to check if the input contains only digits.

```
if (ctype_digit($mystr)) {
    // looks like a non-negative integer
    $value = (int)$mystr;
}
```

Another way would be to use several regex statements to check if the string looks like a double value, a boolean value, an integer value, ...